# Find private key of SSL certificate on IIS using c#

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, encryption

I have an IIS sever with a SSL certificate installed. I am building a web API in C# which will interface with a third party application. I have shared my public key with the third party. The third party will access my API by sending me parameters encrypted with my public key. How do I decrypt the parameter string using  the private key on my IIS server in C#?

Comment: Yu have to create a private key.  Usually you seed the generation of the private key with abyte[].  See : https://yetanotherchris.dev/net-core/ssl-public-private-key-in-netcore-by-example the method : CreateFromPublicPrivateKey

Comment: Use `X509Store` to query the certificate from Windows stores, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=net-5.0 and then access the private key you want. However, stores/certificates/keys are protected by relevant permissions, so your code (application pool) must hold such permissions. Talk to your server administrators if you don't know much about that.